# Concrete5: Can I add stacks in Rich Text Editor?

Tags: richtextbox, concrete5

This is probably not possible but just wanted to know if there is a way to add stacks in Rich Text Editor.

I have a specific requirement where I need to add stacks directly in the text editor and that would make it a lot easier to accomplish.

Let me know if there is a way to do this. I am using Concrete 5.6.x.

Answer (score 1):

No, stacks can only be added to block area on the design or hard coded into the template.

Why are you looking to do that

Comment: I thought so too... In some of my page types, there are block areas that are only allowed to add a single block. This was done for a specific purpose... Anyway, I may have to rethink my design....